# How to split all words from several lines of a word file? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, file

I have a text file:

```
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

Instruction: Open the file and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

Desired output:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

I'm stuck here:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    lst = line.split()
    lst.append(line)
    lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: is this your homework? because I can see multiple solutions for this. One of them being just appending all words and then using a set to get only distinct ones. and then you can sort it.

Comment: Can you please share your answer?

Comment: @rifat this question is already closed. can't answer.

Comment: Based on the prompt, you should iterate through the lines of the file, split the text into a list of words (like you've done), and append a word only if the word is not in the list. `if word not in lst: lst.append(word)` for example

Comment: It did not. I'm very sorry for the misunderstanding. @JacobCelestine